# inserting node function confusing

Tags: c++, struct, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to understand this function to insert an element into a linked list of sorted integers in ascending order, however, there are parts of the code that are confusing me...

```
Node* insert (int x, Node *p) {

 if (p==nullptr)
   return cons(x,nullptr); //inserts the new node at front of list,before node with nullptr?
 if (x < = p-> val)
    return cons(x,p); //this also inserts node at front of the list?
 //now the rest of the function is where I get confused...
 Node *prev=p; //so this is not allocating new memory, so what exactly does it mean?
 Node * after=prev->next; 
 //prev->next is pointing at whatever after is pointing to but after has no address?

 while (after!=nullptr && x > after->val) { //whats going on here?
   prev=after;
   after=after-> next;
 }

 prev->next=cons(x,after);
 return p;
}
```

Comment: The best way to understand pointer manipulations is to use pencil and paper and draw them, e.g. as arrows and boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node* insert (int x, Node *p) {

 if (p==nullptr)
 return cons(x,nullptr); 
//inserts the new node at front of list,before node with nullptr?
if (x < = p-> val)
return cons(x,p); //this also inserts node at front of the list?
```

The code above takes care of inserting the new element at the beginning of the linked list. There are two instances for this to happen:

1. if the head, which is p in this case, is NULL.
2. if the element that p is pointing to has a value greater than the current element to be inserted.

Now going forward...

```
//now the rest of the function is where I get confused...
Node *prev=p; 
//so this is not allocating new memory, so what exactly does it mean?
```

This is just like a temporary pointer which can be used to traverse the linked list. So you store the head 'p' in the prev pointer.

```
Node * after=prev->next; 
//prev->next is pointing at whatever 
//after is pointing to but after has no address?
```

This is a pointer that would store the next element of head.

```
 while (after!=nullptr && x > after->val) { //whats going on here?
   prev=after;
   after=after-> next;
 }
 prev->next=cons(x,after);
 return p;
}
```

Here, this looks a little buggy. You might want to do something like this, instead:

```
While(prev->data >= inputdata && (after->data < inputdata || after == NULL)
{
  //insert your inputdata here because it is greater than the previous but less than after
 // or after is NULL.
}
```

I hope this clarifies your confusion. Let me know if you have any questions.